# GCP - VM disappeared after move

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I am breaking out in a sweat now.

I wanted to move a VM to a different zone within the same region. I run

```
gcloud compute instances move move-this-vm --zone xxxx --destination-zone xxxx
```

I checked on the VM after the command has run, it has disappeared!! I can't find it. I did

```
gcloud compute instances list
```

It is not listed. It is not shown on the web console either.

I have created a machine image of a VM before move so I am not worried about data lost. However, I am bizzared.

Is this a common glitch for moving VM using the CLI? In this scenario, what can I do to retrieve the VM? Why does it happen?

Comment: Did you get any error message in your shell while moving your instance to another zone? If so, it would be helpful if you update your post with an error message.
Remember to make sure [requirements](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/moving-instance-across-zones#requirements) are fulfilled and instance is not shutdown state before moving the instance.
As a workaround, I suggest to move the instance manually following the reference in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/moving-instance-across-zones#moving-an-instance-manually)

Comment: Thanks @Nahuel it is done as suggested by the documentation. Don't recall seeing any error message. I tried to move with a test vm again and it works. I wonder if this glitch is common?

Comment: Could you put as an answer to the post the solution/workaround you found to your issue? It would be helpful for other members of the community who are facing similar problems.

Comment: Hi Nahuel, no solution/workaround. I can't reproduce the problem. It could be just a glitch?